# Problema con AngularFire con snapshotChanges()

Tags: angular, firebase

En un servicio tengo esta función:

```
public getAutor(){
  return this.firestore.collection('autores').snapshotChanges();
}
```

Y en un componente tengo esta función:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.servicio.getAutor().subscribe((autorSnapshot)=>{

  this.menu = [];

  autorSnapshot.forEach((autorData) => {
    this.menu.push({
      id: autorData.payload.doc.id,
      data: autorData.payload.doc.data()
    });
  });

});
```

}

Y en la vista html tengo este código:

```
<p>dadasdasda {{menu.data.id}}</p>
```

pero me da error. Enla linea:

autorData.payload.doc.data() qué es lo que hace?... qué es ese data();

snapshotChanges() que ´tipo de variable devuelve?

Comment: Cual es el error? Que te dice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias de probar usando un pipe en la llamada a firebase.

```
    public getAutor(){
    this.firestore.collection('autores').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => autorData.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, data };
      }))
}
```